# Webpack compiler error on typescript interface and static function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

Trying to include files from my react project (create with create-react-app) with webpack using typescript, but I get these errors:

[image: Error message from webpack]

Seems like the loader, ts-loader, is having issues with my interfaces and static functions.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es2017"],
        "removeComments": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es2017",
        "outDir": "lib"
    },
    "include": ["./**/*.ts", "../src/**/*.tsx"],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules/**/*",
      ".serverless/**/*",
      ".webpack/**/*",
      "_warmup/**/*",
      ".vscode/**/*"
    ]
  }
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  //entry: path.join(__dirname, "../index.tsx"),
  devtool: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' : 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.mjs', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    symlinks: false,
    cacheWithContext: false,
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: ['aws-sdk'],
  module: {
    rules: [
      // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
      {
        test: /\.ts|\.tsx$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/**/*'),
        ],
        exclude: [
          [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, '.serverless'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, '.webpack'),
          ],
        ],
        options: {
          transpileOnly: true,
          experimentalWatchApi: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    // new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
    //   eslint: true,
    //   eslintOptions: {
    //     cache: true
    //   }
    // })
  ],
};
```

Note - this webpack.config file resides in a neighbouring folder to the src folder due to it being used for AWS lambdas.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sls",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Serverless webpack example using Typescript",
  "main": "handler.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.17",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "serverless-webpack": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4",
    "webpack": "^4.29.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.737.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "author": "The serverless webpack authors (https://github.com/elastic-coders/serverless-webpack)",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

How to solve these errors? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the webpack config in the same directory as the `src` directory? In other words, are `webpack.config.js` and `src/` siblings?

Comment: No, the webpack.config.js is in a neighbouring folder (call it WF) with the src folder. In the beginning I had it inside the src folder. I can however move WF around, not really bound to a specific location. Please note that the src folder is created from create-react-app and thus using their webpack config in the node modules folder. The project is not ejected.

Comment: Your errors suggest that these files are not getting handled by ts-loader at all. The first error is because the webpack parser doesn't support [class properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) yet. The second error is because `interface` is not a valid JS keyword. So I would suggest checking the `test`/`include` paths in the `ts-loader` config and `tsconfig.json`. And I'm not sure how and why you are using both the `create-react-app` webpack config and a separate one. Are you sure you're launching webpack with the right config?

Comment: True, I will look over my include again. I am however not sure if the includes in the `tsconfig` file is necessary or if they also need to point to wherever webpack is bundling?

The reason I am using 2 webpacks is because I am using `Serverless` framework which dumps all its assets in a separate folder. This folder holds the scripts used by `Serverless` to package (with webpack) and deploy my AWS lambda functions. The reason I am trying to include files outside of this folder is because I need to import stuff from my application to use within some of these lambdas.